# Curious (bad?) behavior creating all-sky projections with matplotlib

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib

I am trying to make a density "all-sky" plot which is complete in RA (i.e 0 to 360 deg) but incomplete in DEC (let's say from -45 to 90 deg).  If I plot this without any projection it is ok, but when I try to plot using the 'mollweide' projection I am not recovering the input, but if I do a little change in the code I do recover the expected behavior (however, I don't have a coherent explanation for this change as you'll see in the example).

Let's see a self-contained example with its outputs to be clearer:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.backends.backend_agg
from math import pi

#array between 0 and 360 deg
RA = np.random.random(10000)*360
#array between -45 and 90 degrees. By construction!
DEC= np.random.random(10000)*135-45

fig = plt.Figure((10, 4.5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='mollweide')
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_xlabel('RA')
ax.set_ylabel('DEC')

ax.set_xticklabels(np.arange(30,331,30))
hist,xedges,yedges = np.histogram2d(DEC,RA,bins=[90,180],range=[[-90,90],[0,360]])
#TO RECOVER THE EXPECTED BEHAVIOUR, I HAVE TO CHANGE -90 FOR -80 IN THE PREVIOUS LINE:
#hist,xedges,yedges = np.histogram2d(DEC,RA,bins=[90,180],range=[[-80,90],[0,360]])
#I DO NOT WHY!

extent = (-pi,pi,-pi/2.,pi/2.)
image = ax.imshow(hist,extent=extent,clip_on=False,aspect=0.5,origin='lower')

cb = fig.colorbar(image, orientation='horizontal')
canvas = matplotlib.backends.backend_agg.FigureCanvasAgg(fig)

fig.canvas.print_figure("image1.png")
```

And the output image is:
[As I am new here I am not allowed to post images, so I will post a link, if it does not work, please write me an email and I can share a Dropbox folder with the images ;)]

[Output Image that I am getting](http://i56.tinypic.com/24mu96s.png)

Where you can see clearly that the RA is OK so it ranges between 0 and 360, BUT the DEC ranges from **-35** to 90 instead of **-45** to 90. So far I do not understand why I am missing 10 deg.

However, if I do a little change in the code, replacing the line

hist,xedges,yedges = np.histogram2d(DEC,RA,bins=[90,180],range=[[**-90**,90],[0,360]]

for

hist,xedges,yedges = np.histogram2d(DEC,RA,bins=[90,180],range=[[**-80**,90],[0,360]]

I get what I think I should get, which is this plot:

[Output Image 2](http://oi53.tinypic.com/2yl1nch.jpg)

[Again, if the link does not work, let me know and I can share a Dropbox folder with you]

where DEC now ranges from -45 to 90 as expected because I created DEC in that way.

However the change of -90 for -80 doesn't make sense (I think).
So probably I am doing something wrong that I can't notice now, or I am misunderstanding something in the code or there is a curious bug in matplotlib??

Please any help/hint/correction would be greatly appreciate it

Eduardo

Comment: Basically, matplotlib doesn't project images.  This is a longstanding bug/limitation.  For a quick and dirty solution, use `pcolormesh` instead of `imshow`.  You can manually reproject it and display it with imshow, but it's more of a pain than it's worth, in most cases.

Comment: Thanks @Joe for your answer.   I finally solved the problem (I think) thanks to your answer and the one posted by Matt Davis in the astropy email list.

This time I used pcolormesh instead of imshow and I got this image:

[Image](http://i53.tinypic.com/2r6l5k6.png)

The only "problem" is that now I cannot show the "grid" (ax.grid(True) is not working), so if someone know how to add the grid, please let me know ;) (although this is just a detail)

If this is useful for someone else, here is the "corrected version" of my code (which produces the image above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is useful for someone else, this is the "corrected version" of my code, which gives as output this [image](http://i53.tinypic.com/2r6l5k6.png).  The main change is to use pcolormesh instead of imshow (as @Joe suggested):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.backends.backend_agg

#array between 0 and 360 deg
#CAVEAT: it seems that is needed an array from -180 to 180, so is just a
#shift in the coordinates
RA = np.random.random(10000)*360-180
#array between -45 and 90 degrees
DEC= np.random.random(10000)*135-45

fig = plt.Figure((10, 5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='mollweide')

ax.set_xlabel('RA')
ax.set_ylabel('DEC')
ax.set_xticklabels(np.arange(30,331,30))

hist,xedges,yedges = np.histogram2d(DEC,RA,bins=[60,40],range=[[-90,90],[-180,180]])

X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.radians(yedges),np.radians(xedges))

image = ax.pcolormesh(X,Y,hist)
ax.grid(True)
cb = fig.colorbar(image, orientation='horizontal')
canvas = matplotlib.backends.backend_agg.FigureCanvasAgg(fig)
fig.canvas.print_figure("image4.png")
```

Answer (score 3):

if you don't mind depending on an external package, you could do this with healpy, that provides a Mollweide projection for the Healpix sky pixellization:

https://github.com/healpy/healpy

See an example similar to your script here:

https://gist.github.com/1215159

More info about healpix:

http://healpix.jpl.nasa.gov/html/intro.htm

Ouput image:
[image: Example hitmap in Mollview]